# Problem on installing openni_kinect

Tags: openni, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got problem on installing with procedure of openni_kinect ([www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect)).

Regarding 3.2 Sourse based installation (electiric), I cannot do " make and make install" and "make debian and sudo dpkg -i *.deb".
I wonder if I could have answer. Thank you.

Jong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12560/problem-on-installing-openni_kinect/) by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-01-08

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-09**:
Please post enough information to be able to reproduce your error and copy and paste the error: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-08**:
Could you post the exact issue to as to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a certain reason you're trying to build it yourself ? Following 3.1 works good enough for me;

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect

Remember its either 3.1 or 3.2, it is not necessary to do both.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2012-01-11**:
Thank you I was confused. I was thinking I need to follow 3.1 and 3.2 as well. Thank you for you answer.